# How can I export images with their metadata from Google Earth Engine to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-cloud

I want to transfer some images from Earth Engine to a Google Cloud Storage bucket. I know that I can use the following code to accomplish this task:

```
Export.image.toCloudStorage({
            image: image,
            bucket: bucket_name,
            fileNamePrefix: file_name_prefix,
            fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF'
        })
```

This stores my image in the form of several chunks inside my bucket. However, I cannot see the image metadata in any of these chunks. Can someone advise me as to how to save the metadata along with the images?

Answer (score 1):

you could for example export a CSV file. This gives a file with the properties of the image and their corresponding values?

```
Export.table.toCloudStorage({
            collection: ee.FeatureCollection([ee.Feature(image)]),
            bucket: bucket_name,
            fileNamePrefix: file_name_prefix,
            fileFormat: 'CSV'
        })
```

If you have multiple images in one collection, you can also export the collection in once.

Comment: A following question would be how to use the CSV file to reconstruct the image to exactly what it looks like before its export?